# Scraping: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'content' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi would you please help me with this code? I am getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'content' referenced before assignment`
 when trying to run the script. I tried different indentation but still error.

It works with only 2 for loops so `for title` and `for price` Thank you much

```
def tickets(request):

    ticket_offer = []

    url = 'some random URL'

    result = requests.get(url)
    content_data = BeautifulSoup(result.content, features="html.parser")

    for title in content_data.find_all('div', {"class": "singleTipTitle"}):
        for price in title.find_all('span', {"class": "price"}):
            for time in price.find_all('div', {"class": "meta"}):


                ticket = {
                    'title': title.text,
                    'price': price.text,
                    'time': time.text
                }

                ticket_offer.append(ticket)
                content = {'ticket_offer': ticket_offer}
                print(ticket_offer)

    return render(request, 'tickets/tickets.html', content)
```

Comment: `content` is only defined if the for loop executes.  If there is no `div class= "singleTipTitle"` it will never execute. But note that you overwrite that variable each time through each of the inner loops; it will only ever have the value of the last execution. I'm pretty sure that isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That is correct I went back and refactored the code.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the following situation: What do you want to be rendered if there is no valid content?

What happens is the following: The three for loops run, and the *last* match is written into the `content variable.

Some of the files you use don't contain any match, so `content` isn't assigned to.

When the function reaches its last line, there is no `content` which could be passed to `render()`, hence the error.